# How do I set vim's default syntax highlighting for all files in a given dir/path?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

If I open a given mail file in `~/maildir-sent/` then file has no syntax highlighting.  Vi has default highlighting for mail files, and I can turn this on manually with

`:set ft=mail`

This doesn't occur by default because mail files there have the awkward name structure `1339174749.7162_2.tm24-s00418:2,S`

How do I make mail files highlighting occur by default?  I.E. I presume this default reads like "all files that are not matched by another syntax highlight definition"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an `autocmd` in your .vimrc:

```
autocmd BufRead ~/maildir-sent/* setlocal ft=mail
```

See `:help autcmd` for more information.

Comment: If there were, say, a `.rb` file in that directory - would it remain highlighted as a Ruby file?

Comment: Generally, no, but it depends on your setup. It's better in `autocommand` if you can be specific about file extensions if you'll have lots of different filetypes requiring specific highlighting in the targeted directory. Since this is a _mail_ directory it seems like you needn't be very specific. You can solve such issues with additional `autocommands` for the directory and specific extensions

Comment: So far this doesn't work for me with vim 7.3, even using `au` instead of `autocommand`.  You've set this ont he right path, but I don't have the solution quite yet.

Comment: @NewAlexandria edited a mistake in the answer, I'd typed `BufEnter` rather than `BufRead`

Comment: sadly not yet, no.  You must be quite close to the syntax, and I've yet to find it, either.  I know that SO is not the place for 'tech support' -but also I find it unlikely that our Vims are very different.  Maybe you have something extra in your `.vimrc`

Comment: @NewAlexandria bah definitely off today: it's `autocmd` **not** `autocommand`. sorry. You should've been seeing _Not an editor command: autocommand ..._ when starting up with that line